# Reading XML fails when the parent node has XMLNS

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument

I have a application where i read the xml information. 
It is working fine, but when my parent node has an XMLNS added into it, it stops working and starts throwing Null reference exception.

What should be the possible solution for this

XML File

```
<Info  xmlns="urn:smilu.com">
  <Number>123456</Number>  
  <Gender>2</Gender>
  <NamesEng>
    <First>FirstName</First>
    <Second>SecondName</Second>
    <Third>ThirdName</Third>
    <Fourth>FourthName</Fourth>
    <Fifth>FifthName</Fifth>
    <Sixth>SixthName</Sixth>
  </NamesEng> 
</Info>
```

My C# code for reading is

```
 NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);                
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:smilu.com");

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(_LabourXMLInfo);

string Number = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Number", nsMgr).InnerText;
```

The above code works perfectly if i remove the **xmlns** from the Info node. But, with xmlns added to it, shows me exception.
Kindly help me on this.

Comment: I tried but didn't worked

Comment: I Solved the question. XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);   and kept ns: as prefix in all the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring the XML namespace - but you're not actually **using** it (referring to it).

Change your code to:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(_LabourXMLInfo);

// define XML namespace manager based on the XmlDocument's NameTable
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:smilu.com");

// add a "ns:" prefix to the XPath expression here!
string Number = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns:Number", nsMgr).InnerText;
```