# Reading a XML file using C# not working for some xml files

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read following xml file. I've used XML and LINQ but neither of them show any values.I can't find any mistakes on the code.
I've followed [This](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/open-and-read-xml-in-c-examples-using-linq-xmlreader-xmldocu/310) example it's working fine with XML that shown there.

```
<dataSet>
<transactions>
<trans>1</trans>
<Amount>1000</Amount>
<Name>1000</Name>
<Type>Income</Type>
<Date>2022-04-21T00:00:00+05:30</Date>
</transactions>
</dataSet>
```

I've use this code.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadXMLInCsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create XMLDocument object
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            //returns url of main directory which contains "/bin/Debug"
            var url = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

            //correction in path to point it in Root directory
            var mainpath = ("F:\\Education\\Test\\new.xml");
            //load xml file
            xmlDoc.Load(mainpath);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/dataSet/transactions");

            
            var NodeStr = "";

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                NodeStr = NodeStr + "\nTransaction " + node.SelectSingleNode("trans").InnerText;
               


            }
            Console.WriteLine(NodeStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `dataSet`, not `dataset`.

Comment: Thanks,checked with that still not getting results.So I've edited the above code as well

Comment: It is working with the correct `dataSet` writing. Recompile your code and recheck the `new.xml` file. The code in your question is correct.

Comment: When I copied the above-pasted XML it is worked fine.But when I tried it with C# generated file it is not working. Can encoding affect this?

Comment: This seems fine for me, if you are just trying to print Transaction 1.  Since I don't have your local file, I just read the string in without error.  I commented the line with var url out because it doesn't seem to be used.  You need to check the load from file.  Inspect XmlDoc after you load the xml into and see what you have.  Here is a fiddle.  I copied your code directly, with slight modifcation to read the string instead of loading the file: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EOXtBN

Comment: In local file 1st element is look like this <DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet.xsd">. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, if you include that it stops working.  I edited the fiddle.  If you remove the xmlns node it works.  I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: does this link help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757201/reading-xml-fails-when-the-parent-node-has-xmlns

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: It might be simplest to just use replace to remove the xmlns from the string before loading it.  Check the updated fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EOXtBN

Comment: If that's not an option I have added support for use of NameManager to the fiddle.  I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml DataSet node has a namespace attribute, so you'll either need to remove it or use XmlNamespaceManager to handle it.  Here is a fiddle with both:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EOXtBN

In the first, I load the xml into a string, then use .Replace:

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(getXML().Replace(" xmlns='tempuri.org/DataSet.xsd'", ""));
```

Probably not optimal, because that namespace is probably there for a reason, but it's possible this could be an option for you.  It's the one I got to work first.

Second, I use XmlNamespaceManager to handle the parsing.  It doesn't add that much overhead:

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(getXML());
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "tempuri.org/DataSet.xsd");
        
nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:DataSet//ns:transactions", nsmgr); 
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) {
  NodeStr = NodeStr + "\nTransaction " + node.SelectSingleNode("ns:trans", nsmgr).InnerText;       
}
```

Also, bear in mind that you can just include ns:trans in the xpath for the nodelist, like so:

```
nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:DataSet//ns:transactions//ns:trans", nsmgr); 
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) {
  NodeStr = NodeStr + "\nTransaction " + node.InnerText;       
}
Console.WriteLine(NodeStr);
```

And you can use += to clean it up a little more, too:

```
nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:DataSet//ns:transactions//ns:trans", nsmgr); 
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) {
  NodeStr += "\nTransaction " + node.InnerText;       
}
Console.WriteLine(NodeStr);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, This is working.I was trying to do that with LINQ

Comment: I saw a LINQ solution, but it seemed like a lot of overhead comparatively.  The name manager is pretty simple.  Also I updated the answer to note that you can alter the xpath selector to get all the trans nodes into the nodelist to start with, then you don't have to select the trans node inside your loop.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code by modifying as follows, But it doesn't work for me.

xmlDoc.Load(mainpath);
string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(mainpath);

Comment: I thought you said it was working for you?

Answer (score 2):

I'd note this sort of thing is generally much nicer in the more modern LINQ to XML API. It might look something like this (though there are many ways to skin a cat):

```cs
XNamespace ns = "tempuri.org/DataSet.xsd";

var doc = XDocument.Load(mainpath);

var lines =
    from dataSet in doc.Elements(ns + "dataSet")
    from transactions in dataSet.Elements(ns + "transactions")
    from trans in transactions.Elements(ns + "trans")
    select $"Transaction {trans.Value}";

var nodeStr = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

Console.WriteLine(nodeStr);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o6Jk1X) for a working demo.

Comment: Very nice, I like this a lot.  You can also chain those Elements: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YT9O6E

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file have  and you are parsing it via dataset. "s" is in lowercasein your code. set it to
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/dataSet/transactions");

Also check the path to your XML is correct.

Comment: Thanks,checked with that still not getting results.So I've edited the above code as well